# Convert array inside of a Swift Struct to NSdictionary

Tags: swift, objective-c, struct, nsdictionary

Below is my code which the `DataModel` struct is converted to a `NSDictionary`

```
struct DataModel: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let carID: String
    let ownerId: String
    let services : [Service]
    
    var dictionary : [String : Any] {
        return ["id": id,
                "carID": carID,
                "ownerID": ownerId,
                "services": services]
    }
    var nsDictionary : NSDictionary {
        return dictionary as NSDictionary
    }
}

struct Service: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let availableQuantity, usedQuantity: Int
    let discountedPrice: Double
    let discountPercent: Double?
}
```

I call the `DataModel` by doing `response.nsDictionary`

Inside the response my data is structured correctly so I can work with it in Objective C except for my `Services` array. The `Service` response looks like...

`services = (“App.MyClassName.Service(id: \”112STT\”, availableQuantity: 1, usedQuantity: 1, discountedPrice: 20.0, discountPercent: Optional(0.0))"`

How can I get this response data structured the same as my `DataModel` struct?

Comment: Do the same (provide a "nsDictionary", or create a Objective-C compatible class, that can be initialized from a Swift struct `Service`) , or use `class` directly instead of `struct`... But you'll still have your CoreData issue.

Comment: Where would I call my `Services.nsDictionary` though? I tried in the `DataModel` but got several different errors

Comment: `"services": services]` => `"services": services.map{ $0.nsDictionary} ]`, where `nsDictionary` is a var on `Service` following the same logic as the one in `DataModel`.